# Why this Haskell code never terminates?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I recently wrote some Haskell code and it never terminates. After I carefully examined my code, the problem boiled down to the following code piece

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ let a = 10 in
               let a = a in
               a :: Int
```

I guess this must have something to do with the laziness of Haskell since the same code terminates in OCaml. However, if I wrote the following code instead

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ let a = 10 in
               let b = a in
               b :: Int
```

the code would have no problem terminating at all. I can't get the reason since in the original code, the two a's should be considered as two different variables. I don't know why the naming of them has anything to do with the semantic of the program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is that, unlike OCaml, `let` bindings in Haskell are **recursive by default**. So `let x = x in ...` is equivalent to OCaml's `let rec x = x in ...` and is a circular definition.

This is why shadowing variable names in Haskell (ie defining `a` multiple times) is considered bad style and even has a compiler warning, which you can turn on with the `-Wall` flag or more specifically `-fwarn-name-shadowing`.

This default makes more sense in Haskell than OCaml because, thanks to laziness, circular values (rather than just recursive functions) are actually useful. `let x = 1:x` gives us an infinite list of `1`, which we can use just like a normal list.

At the same time, some people don't like this for basically exactly the reason you ran into here: it's possible to introduce unintuitive infinite loops in your code, which makes some errors and typos harder to track down. This is also confusing because, by necessity, `<-` bindings in do-notation *are not* recursive by default, which is a bit inconsistent.

Comment: The situation with `<-` is much, much worse.

Comment: @yatima2975 I've used `do rec` before. It's actually a clean way to solve certain things.

Answer (score 5):

The second binding (`a = a`) shadows the other one. The first example is (almost) exactly equivalent to

```
main = print $ let xyz = 10 in
               let a = a in
               a :: Int
```

and I hope it's clear why that one doesn't terminate! You can get GHC to warn you about this by using the `-fwarn-name-shadowing` flag (or by entering `:set -fwarn-name-shadowing` in GHCi)